# How to solve the problem of the environment

Tags: apk

: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'.
debug.dart:373
Try inserting an identifier before ')'.
if (alternative != )
^
: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
debug.dart:374
ErrorHint(alternative),
^
: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'.
debug.dart:390
Try inserting an identifier before ')'.
if (built == ) {
^
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)

I tried updating flutter to the latest version